# dividing big functions efficiently

Tags: c, embedded

I am currently working to develop a Guideline to improve testability for model based C programming in the area of Embedded Systems.

The first thing I came across was that they created very big (e.g 4k lines) Functions.
For testing issues I would like to suggest to divide the code in smaller pieces.
But I found some sort of a problem and would like to now the most efficient way to solve this.

Imagine the former 4k-lines functions had, lets say 10, local variables.
Now I need to pass this variables around to each function that uses them.
What would be the best, meaning most efficient, way to do this.

At present I have two ideas, both with some disadvantages:

1. Pass the locals by reference to the functions that need them. I need to use References, because many functions change something about the variables. Disadvantage: Reference goes to Heap -> speed decreases.
2. Make to locals visible on file level. Disadvantage: overall more memory usage because variables have a longer lifespan.

Is there maybe an other way that reduces the disadvantages?

Comment: for the currios people: the tool for the model development is ASCET

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the entire 4,000-line function manages to get by on 10 variables, I think you can count yourself lucky.

I would clean it by collecting the variables in a structure, which is instantiated inside the first function, and which is then shared with sub-functions by passing them a pointer. Performance should be very close to what you had.

Also, there are no "references" in C, it can be kind of confusing to use that terminology.

Comment: well 10 where a understatement, there are more in reallity like 30-40

Comment: I agree and I may add that either the variables are related which is why the subfunctions need all of them (then use a struct) or the variables are not related and IMO different subfunctions will require a different subset of the variables.

Comment: it's more like every function needs a few of them

Answer (score 1):

Form one structure that has the variable you want to pass and send that structure variable/structure pointer to any functions you call. This will reduce passing more argumnets